# SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

Estava criando uma ferramenta em Python, porém quando fui rodar ele fica dando esse erro. Trecho do código:

```
while True:
        opcao = int(input("Digite a opcao desejada: ")
        if opcao == 1:
            arquivo = open("textos.txt", 'w')
```

Quando eu rodo aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Falta fechar um parentese na linha anterior

Answer (score 0):

Faltou fechar um parentese, veja:

```
while True:
    opcao = int(input("Digite a opcao desejada: "))
    if opcao == 1:
        arquivo = open("textos.txt", 'w')
```